# How to describe the purely grammatical "how" in common informal speech

Tags: grammar

I translate from Finnish, and I've noticed that Finnish and English use the word "kuinka"/"how" both as an adverb to mean the manner in which a thing is done and as a mere relative clause marker, in sentences like "I saw how she was standing in the window", or "Did you see how he ran away when we came in?", where the meaning is not that I saw the manner in which she was standing or the manner in which he ran away, but the mere fact that she was standing there, or he ran away. Would the "how" in these kinds of sentences be classified as a relative pronoun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example sentences, "how" means "that" and seems to be **a conjunction** rather than **a relative pronoun.**

From [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/how):

> **CONJUNCTION**
>   You use how after certain adjectives **and verbs to introduce a statement or fact,** **often something that you remember or expect other people to know about.**
>
> - It's amazing **how** people collect so much stuff over the years.
> - It's funny **how** I never seem to get a thing done on my day off.
> - It's important to become acutely aware of **how** your eating ties in with your stress level.

From [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/how)

**CONJUNCTION**

> That: I told them **how** I had once been bitten by a snake.

Other dictionaries ([**Lexico**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/how), for instance),  classify "how" as **an interrogative or relative adverb**, though.

> how - usually interrogative adverb and relative adverb.   The way in which; that.
>   ‘she told us how she had lived out of a suitcase for a week’

Comment: I don't think they actually mean "the way in which" in the examples I gave. If I said, "I saw how he ran away when we came in." it wouldn't be logical to respond, "How did he run away?". Because you're not talking about him running quickly or awkwardly or anything--just that he ran away, in no particular manner. If you see what I mean. In other words, "how" here is used exactly like the relative pronoun "that".

Comment: Right--a conjunction, not a relative pronoun. Thanks!